# Can Resharper (2016.1 C#) suggest exceptions to catch with a try catch block?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, resharper

Can Resharper or an existing plugin for resharper suggest exceptions to catch with a try catch block?

For example, File.ReadAllText throws the following exceptions, are there any existing plugins that will allow resharper/intellisense to display these as I type the catch block?

[image]

edit: Added a link so you can vote for the resharper suggestion
https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000073730-Suggest-exceptions-to-catch-when-typing-try-catch-block

Comment: You can also raise up this idea on the ReSharper Community forum: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366389-ReSharper-Community

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: Added a link so people can vote on the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Exceptional for ReSharper](https://github.com/CSharpAnalyzers/ExceptionalReSharper) does something similar. It suggests exceptions to catch, not in IntelliSense, but when statically analyzing the code.

It is of course dependent upon the XML Documentation of all called methods to contain the possible exceptions thrown.

Comment: Thanks. It also does lots of other things.